# Xtend: Add element to array in for-loop

Tags: arrays, xtend

I am trying to do the simplest operation in Xtend, but don't know how. I want to add an `double` value to an `double[]` array inside a for-loop.

For example:

```
def do(EList<MyObject> list) {
    var double[] array = newDoubleArrayOfSize(list.size);
    for (i : 0 ..< list.size) {
        array[i] = list.get(i).myValue;
    }
    return array;
}
```

The forth line shows an error, because I can't use `array[i] = ...`.

How do I implement that in Xtend? Haven't found anything in the user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xtend has a different ("list-like") syntax for accessing array elements, see the [related documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#arrays) for details:

> Retrieving and setting values of arrays is done through the extension
>   methods get(int) and set(int, T) which are specifically overloaded for
>   arrays and are translated directly to the equivalent native Java code
>   myArray[int].

So your code should be:

```
def method(EList<MyObject> list) {
    var double[] array = newDoubleArrayOfSize(list.size);
    for (i : 0 ..< list.size) {
        array.set(i, list.get(i).myValue);
    }
    return array;
}
```

---

You can further simplify your method by omitting semicolons and the type declaration of the `array` variable:

```
def method(EList<MyObject> list) {
    val array = newDoubleArrayOfSize(list.size)
    for (i : 0 ..< list.size) {
        array.set(i, list.get(i).myValue)
    }
    return array
}
```

Another alternative is to write your method in a more *functional* style. If you can replace `EList` with `List` (or `EList` extends/implements `List`) then you could simply write:

```
def double[] method(List<MyObject> list) {
    list.map[myValue]
}
```

In this case you must explicitly declare the return type as `double[]` because otherwise it would be inferred as `List<Double>`.

(Just one more thing: usually collections are preferred over arrays because they are more flexible and have more rich APIs, and Xtend has some additional goodies as well like [collection literals](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html#collection-literals).)

Comment: Thank you very much Snorbi, this helped me a lot!